# I'm storing an object in script properties but it comes back as a string

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm storing my simple object (just seven values) in script properties but when I get it back it seems to be a string. Is there a fast way to cast it back? I could save these as individual properties if necessary but that is less tidy.

```
  var myObject = {
    email: range[0][1],
    sitecode: range[0][2],
    x: range[0][3],
    x: range[0][4],
    x: range[0][5],
    region: range[0][6],
    x: range[0][7] 

  }

  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('globals', myObject);
```

so far so good, then we call this

```
 var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var myObject = userProperties.getProperty('globals');
  Logger.log(myObject);
  Logger.log(userProperties.getKeys());
  Logger.log(myObject.region);
  Logger.log(myObject['region']);
```

but get this

```
[19-05-02 13:59:22:626 PDT] {sitecode=TEST, x=x, x=x, x=x, region=North America, x=x, email=x}
[19-05-02 13:59:22:642 PDT] [globals]
[19-05-02 13:59:22:643 PDT] undefined
[19-05-02 13:59:22:643 PDT] undefined
```

I'd like the last two logger lines to return "North America".The fact that they don't says to me that this is a string not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `PropertiesService` and `CacheService` store their keys and values as strings, so when you try to save an object its string representation is stored.

One solution is to leverage [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to first serialize the object as a JSON string and then store it, and when you later retrieve the object you use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get back the original object.